# Make shell aliases declaratively depend on packages

Tags: nix, nixos

In NixOS, definitions of shell aliases can be defined inside the configurations.nix file like so:

```
environment.shellAliases = {
  "my_some_cmd" = "some_cmd -flag 123";
}
```

This gets assigned even when the referred command (here: `some_cmd`) is not available in the system. Say, this command is included in a package. So it would be desirable to declare that the alias should only be assigned if the package is installed.

How could that be done? Would I have to just work with an wrapping if-statement or are there other ways to archive this?

If the if statement is the way to go, how could that be implemented?

Comment: Write a shell function that automates alias creation if some related command is not found in the path, and use it over and over and over.

Comment: would this be a trivial thing? I mean, how to detect if a word is a command or a parameter. eg: 'alias my="cmd a_file $(echo xyz)"' . However, I'm not too much into bash scripting, so maybe I'm missing sth.

Comment: Either the alias name and the command name is the same, or you'd have to tell it what command's existence to check.

Comment: alright, got you know. however, this would check if certain commands are available, it wouldn't check on a package/derivation level, which I think I'd prefer here though.

Comment: Then check on a package/derivation level! Why don't you explain what you want, so that somebody can show you how to do it. E.g., show how you'd check yourself from the command line. But if it were me, if I can't find "vim" on my `PATH`, it doesn't matter what package is belongs to-- I need to provide a substitute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bypass the need to install the package by using the full path to the command, example:

```
environment.shellAliases = {
  "colored-tree" = "${pkgs.tree}/bin/tree -C";
};
```